# PL/SQL procedure getting error after right compilation

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE

PROCEDURE D_TAB_BONUS
(
EMP_ID   D_EMP.EMPID%TYPE,
SALARY_INC  D_EMP.SALARY%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN

INSERT  INTO D_BONUS(EMP_ID,SALARY_INC) 
SELECT EMPID,SALARY FROM D_EMP
WHERE EMPID=EMP_ID;

COMMIT;

END;
```

This gives the error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
Execute D_TAB_BONUS
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'D_TAB_BONUS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action
```

Comment: Asking in all caps is like shouting and is likely to get you downvoted to oblivion

Answer (score 3):

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'D_TAB_BONUS'

Call the procedure with the correct number and type of arguments. It looks like you are not supplying any.